# Pig UDF Maxmind GeoIP Database Data File Loading Issue

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

The following code works when I execute the Pig script locally while specifying a local GeoIPASNum.dat file. However, it does not work when run in MapReduce distributed mode. What am I missing?

### Pig job

```
DEFINE AsnResolver AsnResolver('/hdfs/location/of/GeoIPASNum.dat');

loaded = LOAD 'log_file' Using PigStorage() AS (ip:chararray);

columned = FOREACH loaded GENERATE AsnResolver(ip);

STORE columned INTO 'output/' USING PigStorage();
```

### AsnResolver.java

```
public class AsnResolver extends EvalFunc<String> {

    String ipAsnFile = null;

    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        try {
            LookupService lus = new LookupService(ipAsnFile,
                    LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
            return lus.getOrg((String) input.get(0));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return null;
    }

    public AsnResolver(String file) {
        ipAsnFile = file;
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: you should initialize the LookupService out of exec...Yet ,it has nothing to do with your question .hehe

Comment: I'll be sure to do that. Good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a string reference to an HDFS path and the LookupService constructor can't resolve the file.  It probably works when you run it locally since the LookupService has no problem with a file in your local FS.

Override the getCacheFiles method:

```
@Override
public List<String> getCacheFiles() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(1);
    list.add(ipAsnFile + "#GeoIPASNum.dat");
    return list;
}
```

Then change your LookupService constructor to use the Distributed Cache reference to "GeoIPASNum.dat" :

```
LookupService lus = new LookupService("GeoIPASNum.dat", LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for "Distributed Cache" in this page of the Pig docs: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/udf.html

The example it shows using the getCacheFiles() method should ensure that the file is accessible to all the nodes in the cluster.